# Can't cut/copy and paste from MS Excel to MS Project Pro

Tags: microsoft-excel, windows-10, microsoft-project

Excel 2013, Project 2010 Pro, Windows 10.

I have an Excel worksheet.  Column A is populated by a list of 10 names, each in their own cell (A1-A10).  I used to be able to highlight and copy (ctrl-C) all 10 names and then paste (ctrl-V) them into the Task Name field in Project.  I am able to cut/copy and paste from Excel to Word no problem and vice versa.  But, for some reason Project stopped accepting anything cut or copied from outside of Project.  ﻿When I try to paste from Excel to Project I either get a blank field or I get the last thing cut or copied from within Project.  It's almost as if Project is using some internal clipboard instead of the Windows Clipboard.  I can cut/copy and paste fine from Excel to Word or anything else.  Any ideas?

Comment: I've noticed that I can copy from Excel to a bran new blank Project, then copy from that blank project to my project.  So there must be something in my Project itself that is disallowing the paste from Excel.

Comment: Try pasting with `Ctrl+Alt+v`. Does it work?

Comment: No luck with ctrl-alt-v.

If I open a bran new project it will allow me to cut and paste from Excel until I copy or cut once from within Project, after that it will only paste what is cut or copied from within itself.

Answer (score 2):

Ran a repair install on both Excel and Project.  That solved the problem.

Thanks everyone.